# Observe add and remove events from ArrayList

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In my applcation I'm trying to implement the MVVM design pattern with the Android Architecture library. For this I have created a `ViewModel` class with some `LiveData` objects in it.

```
public class NotesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Note>> allNotes;
    private MutableLiveData<Note> selectedNote;

    public LiveData<Note> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    // ...
```

In my UI the user is able to add and remove notes. For this I thought it would be enough to create add and remove methods in my `NotesViewModel` and operate directly on the ArrayList like so:

```
    // ...

    public void addNote(Note note) {
        notes.add(note);
        allNotes.setValue(notes);
    }
}
```

My problem with this solution is that I am not able to get the specific note which was removed or added by the user; only the whole list. So how should I do this? Do I have to create a `LiveData` object for each event the user can execute? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a really nice way to handle this problem with `ObservableArrayList`. I created a library for this [here](https://github.com/Cilenco/LiveAdapter) and added some useful, additional features. Please fell free to send me any feedback (this is my first library) and pull requests.

Please note the the `README` is currently not up to date because I'm changing some thing internally. I will update it as soon as possible. I also will add a sample application soon.